# Using Recursion to Find Coordinates in an array

Tags: javascript, recursion, underscore.js

I need to use underscore JS and recursion to go through the array, and push the coordinates to a new array. The code was working earlier prior to recalling the function recursively, so how can I imporve my recursion integration?

```
var array = [[1, 23, 5, 6],
         [7, 9, 37, 34]];

function search(num, column) {
  var boolean = _.contains(array[column], num),
      coordinates = [];

  if (boolean === true) {
    coordinates.push(_.indexOf(array[column], num));
    coordinates.push(column);
    console.log(coordinates);

  } else if (boolean === false) {
    return search(num, column++); 

  } else if (column === array.length) {
    if(boolean === false) {
      console.log('No number present');
    }
  }
}


search(9, 0);
```

Comment: I don't know what you want the result to be. Should it be all nested arrays that contains the search term? I also don't know why you want recursion for a 2D array, but I do know that your second `else if` will never be reached.

Answer (score 0):

Your check for `column === array.length` is in the wrong place and will never get called. Additionally, `column++` will increment column but **returns the old value**, so you will end up calling `search` with column 0 every time. Use `column + 1` instead.

Try this:

```
function search(num, column) {
  if (!column) {
    // This statement allows you to omit the column parameter.
    // So you can call 'search(9);' and it will assume the column is 0.
    column = 0;
  }
  if (column >= array.length) {
    console.log('No number present');
    return null;
  }
  if (_.contains(array[column], num)) {
    var coordinates = [_.indexOf(array[column], num), column];
    console.log(coordinates);
    return coordinates;
  } else {
    return search(num, column + 1);
  }
}
```